# Grid columns not align and text-tranform will not work for links within navigation bar

Tags: html, css

I created an inline grid layout for a navigation bar consisting of two columns: logo and nav links. The links are still not inline with the logo. Also, I'm trying to text-transform the link text to be capitalized, but not getting desired result.

Tried modifying the grid and used different padding, but doesn't seem to the correct approach.

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Robo', sans-serif;
}

.navbar {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template: auto auto;
  grid-column-gap: 680px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(196, 196, 196);
  background-color: #F7F9F9;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}

.logo {
  grid-column: 1/2;
}

.links {
  grid-column: 2/2;
}

.logo h1 {
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: 340;
}

.links a {
  text-transform: capitalize;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-left: 40px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="navbar">
    <div class="logo">
      <h1>Rick Wilson</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="links">
      <a href="#">Experience</a>
      <a href="#">Projects</a>
      <a href="#">Technology Stack</a>
      <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: why the Huge column gap?

Comment: I wanted two columns for the grid and wanted them to appear on each side of the page. I'm sure there is a better technique here, but I didn't know of any off hand.

Comment: yes but why a big gap? ... if you remove it you almost good

Comment: When I remove the gap, the links almost look centered which is not what I'm going for.

Comment: The text-transform seems to be working fine.  Did you mean `text-transform: uppercase`?

Comment: Ah yes, I was using the incorrect value. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Also, I'm trying to text-transform the link text to be capitalized,
>   but not getting desired result.

What is the desired result? Do you maybe want `uppercase`?

Made some adjustments to your grid layout, is this what you need?

```css
body {
  font-family: "Robo", sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(196, 196, 196);
  background-color: #f7f9f9;
  padding: 20px;
  align-items: center;
}

.logo {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.links {
  text-align: right;
}

.links a {
  text-transform: capitalize;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <h1 class="logo">Rick Wilson</h1>
  <div class="links">
    <a href="#">Experience</a>
    <a href="#">Projects</a>
    <a href="#">Technology Stack</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I added `display: flex` and `align-items: center` to `.links`

```css
    body {
      font-family: 'Robo', sans-serif;
    }

    .navbar{
      display:inline-grid;
      grid-template: auto auto;
      grid-column-gap: 680px;
      text-decoration: none;
      border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(196, 196, 196);
      background-color:#F7F9F9;
      padding:10px;
      width: 100%;
    }


    .logo {
      grid-column: 1/2;
    }

    .links {
      grid-column: 2/2;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      
    }

    .logo h1 {
      font-size:32px;
      font-weight: 340;
    }

    .links a {
      text-transform: capitalize;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size:20px;
      padding-left: 40px;

    }
```

```html
    <header>
                <nav>
                  <div class = "navbar">
                    <div class = "logo"><h1>Rick Wilson</h1></div>
                    <div class = "links">
                    <a href="#">Experience</a>
                    <a href="#">Projects</a>
                    <a href="#">Technology Stack</a>
                    <a href="#">Contact</a>
                    </div>
                  </div> 
                </nav>
                  </header>
```

Answer (score 0):

add

`display:flex`
`align-items: center` 
`justify-content: space-between`

to `.navbar` so that both of the flex children `.links` and `.logo` will be centered horizontally. Then the `justify-content: space-between` should push each item out to the left and right sides with space in between them.